# Can a fully native Android app call Java?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

Good day.

It is possible to change for example native-plasma, which is a fully native Android app with only C++ and no Java or Kotlin, to be able to call Java?

I have used native-plasma as a base for an application, and now I need to call into third-party libraries, which they provided as Java, of course. But I cannot seem to find a way to now import their libraries and use their classes.

Thanks, help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes you can, The `android_app*` that you get to your `android_main` has a member `ANativeActivity* activity`, and through this you can get a `JavaVM *vm` which you can use to call `AttachCurrentThread` and get a `JNIEnv*`. I'm not sure how you'd go about being able to resolve your third-party Java classes with `FindClass` though.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks a lot for the answer. Shortly before you answered I found a code snippet that suggests exactly this, and I have tried it. I am getting an JNIEnv* pointer, but I get back NULL when I call FindClass on it. Just to test I am not trying to find an external class, I am simply trying to find a class that I added in my app itself.

It may be that the Kotlin/Java does not get compiled with my native app, as I simple went to the app folder and added a java folder and in there added my Kotlin class.

Comment: You should be able to resolve Android SDK classes and standard Java classes, but I'm not sure if it's possible to resolve your own classes since I've never attempted this myself.